# PHP .CSV File reader blank spaces

Tags: php, csv

Hi i have this csv file reader. I have this problem tho, it makes blank cells when it has some special characters like, "ø" "," "-". there might be more. Here is my code:

```
<?php
// inkludere vores footer hvis logget ind
if ($user->is_loggedin() == true) {
    // File selector
    $path = "./assets/csv"; 

    $latest_ctime = 0;
    $latest_filename = '';    

    $d = dir($path);
    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
    // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
    if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
        $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
        $latest_filename = $entry;
    }
    }
    // table start
    echo'<h1 class="text-center">CSV Table</h1>';
    echo'<h6 class="text-center">'.$latest_filename.'</h6>';
    echo '<table id="example" class=" table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">';
    echo'<tbody>';

    $f = fopen("$path/$latest_filename", "r");
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
            $row = $line[0];    // We need to get the actual row (it is the first element in a 1-element array)
            $cells = explode(";",$row);
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($cells as $cell) {
                echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($cell) . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
    }
    fclose($f);
    echo'</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

This is how it is shown when i try show the file.
I will use the | to indicate cells and write "Blank" when it shows a blank cell

|Name|Datum|Property|Criterion|Type|Nominal|Actual|Tol-|Tol+|Dev|

|1)Height|Blank|Blank|Blank|inp|Blank|Blank|Blank|Blank|Blank|

How it should look:

|Name|Datum|Property|Criterion|Type|Nominal|Actual|Tol-|Tol+|Dev|

|1)Height|Blank|Ø|Blank|inp|123,3|123,3|-1|1|-0,24|

Hope this makes sense to you

Comment: please share some example data, and outputs of that data

Comment: ill update the question, with an example of how is is and how it should be

Comment: use `htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_IGNORE)` instead of `htmlspecialchars($cell)`.

Comment: Got the same result with htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_IGNORE)

Comment: Maybe `htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_SUBSTITUTE)` ?

Comment: htmlspecialchars($cell, ENT_SUBSTITUTE) didnt seem to work.

Comment: Did you studied this site? http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: Now i have tried all the different kinds of htmlspecialchars from php.net/htmlspecialchars no change.

Comment: if you have any other examples of an output from a csv file which might suit my needs better, then it would be much appreciated.